# Python Image Library (PIL) error with floating point tiff

Tags: python, image, floating-point, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am writing a script that changes the resolution of a floating point 2K (2048x2048) tiff image to 1024x1024.

#### But I get the following error:

*File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1916, in open*

*IOError: cannot identify image file*

#### My Code:

```
import Image

im = Image.open( inPath ) 
im = im.resize( (1024, 1024) , Image.ANTIALIAS )
im.save( outPath )
```

Any Ideas?

[Download My Image From This Link](http://www.mediafire.com/?dk73ox7na84c6v3)

Also I'm using pil 1.1.6. The pil install is x64 same as the python install (2.6.6)

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these two:

1. open the file in binary mode,
2. give the full path to the file.

HTH!

**EDIT after testing the OP's image:**

It definitively seems like is the image having some problem. I'm on GNU/Linux and couldn't find a single program being able to handle it. Among the most informative about what the problem is have been GIMP:

[image: GIMP error message]

and ImageMagik:

```
display: roadnew_disp27-dm_u0_v0_hr.tif: invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/703.
display: roadnew_disp27-dm_u0_v0_hr.tif: unknown field with tag 18 (0x12) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/703.
```

I did not try it myself, but googling for "python tiff" returned the [pylibtiff](http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/) library, which - being specifically designed for TIFF files, it might perhaps offer some more power in processing this particular ones...

HTH!

Comment: Thanks but nope, doesn't help. Image.open( inPath , 'rb' ) - returns a "Bad mode" error.

Comment: @JaredGlass Can you post the image you are working with? To me it works (without the `rb` mode) with my local TIFF library... I suspect it might be a problem on the file then...

Comment: @JaredGlass - Definitively something weird with the file. See my edits... hope they help you tracking down the problem! :)

Comment: Im using djv to do commandline resolution changes in the meantime and thats working fine so far. I'd prefer to use pil but untill I find a solution djv it is. Thanks for all your help though :)